# TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have this code which is suppose to look for /help command in telegram. So once you type /help in the telegram channel it will give you options. The code is as follows.

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram.ext import filters

# Define your bot token here
TOKEN = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"


def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Welcome to your Telegram bot!")

def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("You requested help. Here are some available commands:\n"
                              "/help - Show this help message\n"
                              "/start - Start the bot")

def handle_message(update, context):
    text = update.message.text
    if text == '/start':
        start(update, context)
    elif text == '/help':
        help_command(update, context)

def main():
    # Initialize the Updater with your bot token
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    # Define the command handlers
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    # Handle non-command messages using a filter
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_message))

    # Start the bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However I am getting this error

```
TypeError: Updater.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

Could you please advise how I can resolve this error.

Comment: just update your `python-telegram-bot` library like this : `pip install --upgrade python-telegram-bot`, and If this solution was helpful to you, please let me know so that I can write it as the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I am using version 20.5 already. What can I do to modify this code for version 20 and above

Comment: you need to use the `telegram.Bot` class to create a bot instance, and then pass that instance to the `Updater` class because in version 20 and above of the `python-telegram-bot` library, the `Updater` class no longer accepts the `token` parameter in its constructor, I will give you an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `telegram.Bot` class and then I passed it to the `Updater` like this:

```
from telegram import Update, Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram.ext import filters

#defining your bot token here
TOKEN = "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN"

def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text("Welcome to your Telegram bot!")

def help_command(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text("You requested help. Here are some available commands:\n"
                              "/help - Show this help message\n"
                              "/start - Start the bot")

def handle_message(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    text = update.message.text
    if text == '/start':
        start(update, context)
    elif text == '/help':
        help_command(update, context)

def main():
    #creating a bot instance
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)

    #creating an updater instance and pass the bot instance
    updater = Updater(bot=bot, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    #defining the command handlers
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help_command))

    #handling non-command messages using a filter
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.Text & ~filters.Command, handle_message))

    #starting the bot
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The **[Updater](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5/telegram.ext.updater.html)** class takes two arguments, **`bot`** and **`update_queue`**.  You'll need to create a [telegram.Bot](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot) instance and an **[asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue)** instance first:

```
from asyncio import Queue
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater

bot = Bot(TOKEN, ...)
update_queue = Queue()

updater = Updater(bot, update_queue)
```

I'm not at all familiar with `Telegram`, and my understanding of `asyncio` is limited, so that is the most help I can offer.  If you aren't sure how to use the queue, I would suggest looking at the documentation links for each of the packages (listed above).

Answer (score 1):

Starting from python-telegram-bot 20.0, the [`Updater`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a0/telegram.ext.updater.html) class no longer supports the arguments `token` and `use_context`. The last version that supports these arguments is [python-telegram-bot 13.15](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.15/telegram.ext.updater.html), so if you just want to use someone else's code written for pre-20.0 versions without refactoring, you can downgrade your python-telegram-bot version by first uninstalling it with:

```
pip uninstall python-telegram-bot
```

and then installing the version 13.15 with:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot==13.15
```